# RGB manipulation, rotation algorithms

Tags: java, arrays, rgb

I'm building a small program to manipulate a couple of RGB arrays and subsequently images, and I'm having troubles regarding my rotation algorithms,

This is my rotation algorithm,

```
   public void rotateRight() {
     RGBColor[][] mirror = new RGBColor[h][w];
         for(int i = 0 ; i < h; i++){
              for(int j = 0 ; j < w; j++){
                  int b = pixel[j][h-i-1].getBlue();
                  int g = pixel[j][h-i-1].getGreen();
                  int r = pixel[j][h-i-1].getRed();
                  mirror[i][j] = new RGBColor(r,g,b);
              }
          }
         pixel = mirror;
   }
```

which is working fine for squared pictures, but for non squared is acting like this:

It's going from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Instead of rotating the actual picture to the right and provide new dimensions, I've got no idea what's causing it, tried everything already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manipulating an image, the most frequent source of mistakes is the inversion of the width and height parameters. And that is also the answer to your problem ! Swapping `h` and `w` in the first snippet should fix it. Note that you could have guessed it since you noticed it was working for square images and not for rectangular ones, which can have only one explanation...

The following snippet performs the rotation you want using `BufferedImage` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResource("input.png"));
    int w = input.getWidth();
    int h = input.getHeight();

    BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(h,w,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int i=0 ; i<h ; i++) 
        for (int j=0 ; j<w ; j++)
            output.setRGB(i,j,input.getRGB(j,h - i - 1));
    ImageIO.write(output,"png",new File("output.png"));
}
```

Since you seem to be using the same convention for your array, it might work for you as well.

Comment: You could add a little bit of code or perhaps specify which `w` and `h` he should swap with which. In this case I believe changing `i < h` to `i < w` and `j < w` to `j < h` will fix the problem.

Comment: yeah but, if I use this code, http://pastebin.com/f2rYY0DJ , i can get it to work on both types of images, but it's not working like it should, it's inverting only the orientation of the non squared ones, instead of rotating it clockwise and grabbing a new width and height, i've tried that also, doesn't seem to work :<. thx man

Comment: You are swapping indexes at many places in your first snippet, you must fix all of these to get your code to work

Comment: @MertcanEkiz yeah, I've updated the question with my most "working" algorithm, thanks for all the help.

Comment: @bknight Uhh, I realize my working code is the same as yours. What are the dimensions of `pixel` before calling this method ? It should be a `w x h` array.

Comment: @Dici yeah pixel is like the original image in w*h dimensions, then i create a mirror of the image while making the rotation, as when we rotate w*h becomes h*w, i always create the mirror with that setting, then in the end, I attribute this mirror, to pixel, finalizing the operation.

Comment: Can you provide your whole code ? I'm pretty sure the mistake is tiny, since your logic and mine are exactly the same and my code works.

Comment: @Dici, http://pastebin.com/am6F7Bjx , there you have the writing algorithm, as well as everything involved with it! thx

Comment: @bknight Is there any advantage in using custom image and color classes ? The above code just uses `BufferedImage` and works fine. Plus, you don't update `h` and `w` after rotating whereas you did in your previous version.

Comment: @Dici I've found where the error was residing, the updating on the h and w was actually setting both on the same values, had to use some sort of mid level variable to make the transition and in the end all worked out well at last, thanks for all the input!

Comment: @bknight Oh, that was obvious ! Congrats :)